# BERT for Text Summarization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding, seq2seq

I'm trying to build a text summarization model using seq2seq architecture in Keras. I've followed this tutorial https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/ and implemented it with Embeddings layer, which works fine. But now I want to use BERT. Can pretrained BERT embeddings be used in such a task, usually I see text classifiation, but not the encoder-decoder architecture used with BERT.

I access BERT model from TF Hub, and have a Layer class implemented from this tutorial https://github.com/strongio/keras-bert/blob/master/keras-bert.ipynb, I also tokenize accordingly with BERT tokenizer, below is my model

```py
enc_in_id = Input(shape=(None, ), name="Encoder-Input-Ids")
enc_in_mask = Input(shape=(None, ), name="Encoder-Input-Masks")
enc_in_segment = Input(shape=(None, ), name="Encoder-Input-Segment-Ids")
bert_encoder_inputs = [enc_in_id, enc_in_mask, enc_in_segment]

encoder_embeddings = BertLayer(name='Encoder-Bert-Layer')(bert_encoder_inputs)
encoder_embeddings = BatchNormalization(name='Encoder-Batch-Normalization')(encoder_embeddings)
encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_size, return_state=True, name='Encoder-LSTM')
encoder_out, e_state_h, e_state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embeddings)
encoder_states = [e_state_h, e_state_c]

dec_in_id = Input(shape=(None,), name="Decoder-Input-Ids")
dec_in_mask = Input(shape=(None,), name="Decoder-Input-Masks")
dec_in_segment = Input(shape=(None,), name="Decoder-Input-Segment-Ids")
bert_decoder_inputs = [dec_in_id, dec_in_mask, dec_in_segment]

decoder_embeddings_layer = BertLayer(name='Decoder-Bert-Layer')
decoder_embeddings = decoder_embeddings_layer(bert_decoder_inputs)
decoder_batchnorm_layer = BatchNormalization(name='Decoder-Batch-Normalization-1')
decoder_batchnorm = decoder_batchnorm_layer(decoder_embeddings)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_size, return_state=True, return_sequences=True, name='Decoder-LSTM')
decoder_out, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_batchnorm, initial_state=encoder_states)
dense_batchnorm_layer = BatchNormalization(name='Decoder-Batch-Normalization-2')
decoder_out_batchnorm = dense_batchnorm_layer(decoder_out)
decoder_dense_id = Dense(vocabulary_size, activation='softmax', name='Dense-Id')
dec_outputs_id = decoder_dense_id(decoder_out_batchnorm)
```

The model builds and after a couple of epochs accuracy rises to 1, and loss drops below 0.5, but the predictions are awful. Since I'm working on a dev set comprised of 5 samples, with max 30 WordPiece tokens and predicting on the same data, I only get the first or maybe two tokens right, then it just repeats the last seen token, or [PAD] token.

Answer (score 2):

There different methods for summarizing a text i.e. Extractive & Abstractive.

> **Extractive summarization** means identifying important sections of the text and generating them verbatim producing a subset of the
> sentences from the original text; while **abstractive summarization**
> reproduces important material in a new way after interpretation and
> examination of the text using advanced natural language techniques to
> generate a new shorter text that conveys the most critical information
> from the original one.

For a transformer based approach you just need an additional attention layer which you can add to an encoder-decoder model or you can use pre-trained transformers (fine tune them maybe) like BERT, GPT, T5, etc.

You can have a look at : https://huggingface.co/transformers/

For Abstractive Summarization T5 works pretty well. Here's a nice and simple example : https://github.com/faiztariq/FzLabs/blob/master/abstractive-text-summarization-t5.ipynb

For Extractive Summarization you may take a look at : https://pypi.org/project/bert-extractive-summarizer/

There's a paper (**Attention Is All You Need**) that explains transformers pretty well, you may also take a look at it : https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762

Answer (score 0):

I think [this work](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/5bfcd0485ece086ebcbed2d008813037968a9e58/examples/run_summarization_finetuning.py?fbclid=IwAR33GxjYWIGKDMxZ3iZBr2JYFUZUULnXzG4H5nuKpuJRrxFPSp8yDLOO9cc) might prove helpful, there are many other text summarization models that you can try out [here](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods) they also contain their own [blogs](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods#blogs) to discuss into detail how they were made

Hope this is helpful